# How to group XML into JSON

Tags: json, xml, powershell

I have an XML document in this format

```xml
<rss>
  <channel>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <image>img_32.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>2</id>
      <image>img_42.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <image>img_52.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>3</id>
      <image>img_62.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>4</id>
      <image>img_72.jpeg</image>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I'm grouping this data on the ID node, so that i get all the images in a list for each ID.

```psh
[xml]$xml = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://myfeedurl.xml")
$grouped = $xml.rss.channel.item | Group id
$grouped
```

Which returns

```
Count Name        Group
----- ----        -----
    2 1           {item}{item}
    1 2           {item}
    1 3           {item}
    1 4           {item}
```

But I can't figure how use this grouped information using `ConvertTo-Json` in order to end up with JSON in this format.

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "images": [
      {
        "image": "img_32.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "image": "img_52.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "images": [
      {
        "image": "img_42.jpeg"
      }
    ]
  },
  etc...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only get it going by iterating through the nodes and building up some custom objects. Custom objects are required to get the tag naming down the way you want it.  There may be a more elegant way to iterate/check, but this works.

```
[xml]$xml = "<rss>
  <channel>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <image>img_32.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>2</id>
      <image>img_42.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <image>img_52.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>3</id>
      <image>img_62.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>4</id>
      <image>img_72.jpeg</image>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>"

$ht = @{}
$xml.rss.channel.item | Foreach {
    $obj = New-Object psobject 
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name 'id' -Value $_.id        
    $img = New-Object psobject
    $img | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name 'image' -Value $_.image
    $imgarr = @($img)
    if ($ht.ContainsKey($_.id))
    {
        $imgarr += $ht[$_.id].images # + $img
    }
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name 'images' -Value $imgarr
    $ht[$_.id] = $obj    
}

ConvertTo-Json $ht.Values -Depth 3
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "id":  "2",
        "images":  [
                       {
                           "image":  "img_42.jpeg"
                       }
                   ]
    },
    {
        "id":  "4",
        "images":  [
                       {
                           "image":  "img_72.jpeg"
                       }
                   ]
    },
    {
        "id":  "1",
        "images":  [
                       {
                           "image":  "img_52.jpeg"
                       },
                       {
                           "image":  "img_32.jpeg"
                       }
                   ]
    },
    {
        "id":  "3",
        "images":  [
                       {
                           "image":  "img_62.jpeg"
                       }
                   ]
    }
]
```